# Optimizing Selenium's exception handling

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code is most likely to throw an exception when it can't locate an element. This tends to happen with some elements more often than others, although I can't be sure it won't be a problem with any given element depending on the conditions.

Setting aside `time.sleep()` and `driver.implicitly_wait`, is the only way to build a fault-free production grade crawler to `wait.until.presence_of_element_located()` for every element? Are there more efficient ways to handle this?

Comment: why driver.implicitly_wait is not good enough?

Comment: @AlexanderStarostin: Because of the variability of the wait. For example, 95% of my element searches may be done in 1 second or less, but a few of them could take 2 or 3 seconds. I don't want to do an implicit wait of 3 seconds for everything but I can't mix implicit and explicit. Also, it's easier to handle exceptions to the explicit wait. I can't put every element search inside `try:` just because `implicitly_wait` might return an exception.

Comment: @AutomaticStatic I think you misunderstand how `implicitly_wait` works. It doesn't wait for the full timeout, but rather only waits as long as necessary _up to_ the timeout. Additionally, the timeout can be changed at any time to provide a longer or shorter wait. Of course, I strongly prefer so-called "explicit waits" using `WebDriverWait` Or similar, even if I use a wrapper or helper method, and even for every `find_element`, because I think intent is clearer. I'll refrain from editorializing on whether crawling arbitrary pages with WebDriver is a good idea.